# Using Javascript how to sort the particular field Values in visual force page

Tags: javascript, dynamic-visualforce

How can i  sort the ascending and descending the array of particular field(Date,Name,status,price..etc) values using java script in visual force page

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much same as sorting a regular html table. In short, Visualforce doesn't support that natively. So you need to apply a Javascript library. Here is a list of them:http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/

You can pick up anyone you like and follow the sample code of that library.

Comment: Thanks for your Replay. lance I am not displaying table format. i am passing the values from Remote Action Function and displaying Inner HTML .Those values i need to sort.